# C# / SQLServer: Merge Rows in a table by similar column values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in SQLServer with millions of rows containing x, y, z coordinates:

```
X       Y       Z
2660000 1270000 421.8513
2660000 1270000 -1415.6297
2660000 1269960 421.0372
2660000 1269960 -1415.7926
```

There are always exactly two rows with the same x and y coordinates.

I want to get a table with the following structure:
**x**, **y**, **ztop** (the greater z value of the pair), **zbase** (the lower z value).  Thus the result contains just one row for each pair with the same x,y coordinates.

I tried different ways but no success so far.  Does anybody have an idea how to solve this in C# or directly in SQL Server?

Comment: What did you try, exactly? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use MIN and MAX aggregate functions to get the top and base z values then just group by the x and y columns.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'coords1' )
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE dbo.coords1
    END
    GO

CREATE TABLE coords1 ( [x] DECIMAL(12,4),  [y] DECIMAL(12,4), [z] DECIMAL(12,4) )
GO

INSERT INTO coords1 ( x, y, z)
VALUES(2660000, 1270000, 421.8513),
(2660000, 1270000, -1415.6297), 
(2660000, 1269960, 421.0372),
(2660000, 1269960, -1415.7926)
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'coords2' )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.coords2
END
GO

CREATE TABLE coords2 ( [x] DECIMAL(12,4), [y] DECIMAL(12,4), [ztop] DECIMAL(12,4), [zbase] DECIMAL(12,4) )
GO

INSERT INTO coords2 ([x], [y], [ztop], [zbase])
SELECT [x], [y], MAX([z]) AS [ztop], MIN([z]) AS [zbase]
FROM coords1
GROUP BY x, y

SELECT * FROM coords2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to OTTA and Holly Styles! It was my first post - didn't know how to mark as answered, but now I read the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle it would be as follows, without the GROUP BY clause the aggregate functions, Max and MIN, would be applied over the whole table, with it they're applied to each unique combination of x and y.

```
SELECT x, y, MAX(z), MIN(z) GROUP by x, y
```

Comment: Wow, that easy! Works great in SQL Server too! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Polite thing from your end now is to mark the answer as correct, that way I get the reputation points ;-). Or you could give them to Holly as her(?) answer is more comprehensive though I was quicker.